# How to force foreach to display div without data available from database

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using a foreach to retrieve data from MySQL with a LIMIT 8 on the query, though when I display the data inside the foreach there are blocks(div) missing as there aren't enough data in the MySQL database. I'd like to know if it's possible to auto include 8 divs even tho there aren't any data being inserted into these divs and once there is data then it can update the blocks.

ex.

**css code for the blocks.**

`.g_body-first-left { background-color: #000; width: 200px; height: 300px; }`

This is how I'm displaying the data. PS: don't need to include the query since I'm just trying to retrieve 8 blocks.

```
foreach ($healthHighlighted as $data)
{   
    $highlighted_title      = $data['article_title'];
    $highlighted_content    = $data['article_content'];

    echo
    '
        <div class="g_body-first-left">

        </div>
    ';
}
```

So I'd like for the foreach to display

```
<div class="g_body-first-left">
</div>
```

regardless if there is any data to be displayed or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the quick solution:

```
$cnt = 0;
foreach ($healthHighlighted as $data)
{   
    $highlighted_title      = $data['article_title'];
    $highlighted_content    = $data['article_content'];
    echo '<div class="g_body-first-left">...</div>';
    $cnt++;
}
while ($cnt++<8)
    echo '<div class="g_body-first-left"></div>';
```

Comment: Now I understand exactly what happens which is pretty simple to understand but perfect, thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this:

```
$block_count = 0;
foreach ($healthHighlighted as $data)
{   
    $highlighted_title      = $data['article_title'];
    $highlighted_content    = $data['article_content'];

    echo
    '
        <div class="g_body-first-left">

        </div>
    ';
    $block_count++;
}

for($i=0; $i<(8-$blockcount); $i++){
    echo
    '
        <div class="g_body-first-left">

        </div>
    ';
}
```

That's a quick solution like the other, but it'll work!

Comment: it will not work, as you will display the same amount of empty block as filled ones, but the problem - OP needs display 8 in total, check your code when no data from db at all

Answer (score 0):

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 8; $i++) {
    $data = current($healthHighlighted);
    next($healthHighlighted);

    $highlighted_title      = $data['article_title'];
    $highlighted_content    = $data['article_content'];

    echo '<div class="g_body-first-left">';
    if ($data) {
        echo $data; // your data rendering goes here
    }
    echo '</div>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to insert exactly 8 divs then use the good'ol `for` not `foreach`

```
for($i = 0; $i++; $i < 8)
{
    if(isset($healthHighlighted[$i]))
    {
        $highlighted_title      = $healthHighlighted[$i]['article_title'];
        $highlighted_content    = $healthHighlighted[$i]['article_content']; //i guess this has to 
    }
    echo
    '
        <div class="g_body-first-left">
        </div>
    ';
}
```